# How to pass a function variable from a controller to a directive link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to evaluate a variable through the directive. How can I pass a variable found inside a function from a controller to a directive link? I was able to pass it globally but if a variable is set inside a function it says undefined. I also tried rootScope but to know avail.

Controller

```
$scope.checkForCall = function(){
    $http({
        url: $locationProvider + 'broadcast_call',
        method: "GET"
    }).success(function (data){
        if(data != 'none'){
            $scope.ccards = data.broadcast;
            $scope.hasData = 1;
        }   else    {
            $scope.hasData = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

My Directive

```
 app.directive('cards', function($timeout,$interval){
    return{
        restrict: 'EAC',
        template: '<h1>NOT FOUND</h1>',
        link: function($scope){
               if($scope.hasData == 1){ // UNDEFINE 
                 console.log("Has data")
               }else{
                 console.log("not found")
               }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use your data from $http .success, it is asynchronous change. That means `scope.hasData` would be undefined at first, then change to 0 or 1 at a later time.

For your case you can setup a watcher in your directive so it can do something when it detect changes.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs){ // fix this line as suggested by other poster
     scope.$watch(function(){
         return scope.hasData;
     },
     function() {
         if(scope.hasData == 1){
             console.log("Has data");
         }
         else if(scope.hasData == 0){
             console.log("not found");
         }
         else {
             console.log("not ready yet");
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: I knew it. I was thinking about $apply and $watch but still can't get a good grasp on how it works. I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way.

sample html :

```
<h1 cards dataTwoWayBinding="hasData">
```

JS -

DIRECTIVE

```
app.directive('cards', function($timeout,$interval){
return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope : {
                dataTwoWayBinding:'=dataTwoWayBinding',

            }
    template: '<h1>NOT FOUND</h1>',
    link: function($scope){

            if(dataTwoWayBinding.data==1){
                //code
            }else{
                //code
            } 

    }
};
});
```

CONTROLLER -

```
$scope.checkForCall = function(){
    $http({
        url: $locationProvider + 'broadcast_call',
        method: "GET"
    }).success(function (data){
        $scope.hasData = {}; 
        if(data != 'none'){
            $scope.ccards = data.broadcast;
            $scope.hasData.data = 1;
        }   else    {

            $scope.hasData.data = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

I have not tested code.Please let me know if there is any issue.